# scraping of target href not possible, result is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape a href attribute from Google images. My code looks fine, but something seems to be wrong. I'm posting a screenshot of it, because there is a lot of unnecessary code from Google itself.

[image]

My goal is to reach the href of the first "a" class "wXeWr.islib.nfEiy". But everything I get as a result is undefined. If I'm doing the same with the lower href from the "a" class ="VFACy..." everything works fine. Seems like I can't reach the attribute of the first a class. But why?

This is my code for scraping all href in "MSM1fd" class

```js
async function collectURLs(){       
    let header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36"
    };
    
    return unirest
        .get(URL)
        .headers(header)
            .then((response) => {
                let $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
                const images_results = [];

                $(".isrlc").each((i,el) => {
                    $(el).find("a").each(function(i, link){
                        console.log($(link).attr('href'), true);
                })
            })
        });
}
```

A result is for example looking like this:

```html
undefined true  #seems to be the first href
https://tempsens.com/utility-pressure-gauge.html true #2nd href
```

Comment: those randomly generated clases chnge with eery request.

Comment: I dont think so, because then i also could not find the second href

Comment: You're showing a screenshot from the DOM inspector. Are you certain that the `response.body` html actually contains these values already?

Comment: What page is this, please?